# how to automatically delete a database record after a set time in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I'm looking for a way to delete a database row after a set time in Cakephp.

For example: 
   I have a groups database in which users create groups and invite others to join the group. These groups also have levels which are differentiated by the number of days it will last e.g:

Silver: 30 days.

Gold: 60 days.

Diamond: 120 days.

Is there a way to delete the groups automatically from the database after their time elapses.

Comment: Create a script, run it on cron.

Comment: please, could you tell me how to do that in cakephp?

Comment: I don't use cakephp. Using cron is universal solution for tasks like yours so google something or ask more clarifeid question.